# Падежное окончание

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика

В каком падеже нужно писать слово «речь»: "здесь не идет речи о процедуре"? Когда пишется «речь» и «речи»?

Answer (score 2):

*Здесь не идет речь о процедуре* (слово *речь* в именительном падаже, оно является подлежащим). *Здесь нет речи о процедуре* (очень коряво, но грамматически возможно: нет (чего?) *речи* - родительный падеж в отрицательном предложении).